# Node.js promises sometimes don't execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am developing an application using Node.js. I have been using callbacks but I recently started migrating to promises. My problem is that on the latest electron (12.0.0) and Node 14.15 promises just sometimes don't work. No error or anything, it just doesn't work or takes several seconds to. Check the following snippet

```
    const fs=require('fs/promises')        
    test()

    function test() {
     fs.readFile('views/database_connection_status.html', 'utf-8').then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
     }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
     })
    }
```

The file does exist. Sometimes it loads, and displays correctly and sometimes just nothing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it fail? Or does it just take a long time?

Comment: You can also write `const data = await fs.readFile(...); console.log(data);` Way simpler, cleaner, and easier to maintain IMO

Comment: @evolutionxbox 10 minutes later and nothing. I should note that it's only on the readFile though. I've had issues with it for two days, both the promise and callback version.

Comment: This doesn’t sound like a promise issue. More like a system issue

Answer (score 0):

```
const co = require('co');
const fs = require('fs');

test().then(res => {
    callback(null,res)
}).catch(error => callback(error));

const test = () =>{
    return co(function* (){
        return fs.readFile('views/database_connection_status.html','utf-8)
    }
}
```

Hey, Joseph, you can check out the "co" package for functions with promises, your code will look like the above.
Can read more about it https://www.npmjs.com/package/co